# IN PYTHON why is this 'AA1' not defined

Tags: python

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui as pag 
import keyboard

def location():
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    AA1 = screen.getpixel((821,571))

location()
print(AA1)
```

> NameError: name 'AA1' is not defined

---

Isn't

```
location()
print(AA1)
```

=

```
screen = ImageGrab.grab()
AA1 = screen.getpixel((821,571))
print(AA1)
```

?

---

- If my question is wrong way Please tell me.
- I want to know how I can tell you my situation well

Comment: AA1 is defined inside a function and you are accessing it from outside the function

Comment: `AA1` is local to the function, so you can't access it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either make AA1 a global variable or return its value in location function

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui as pag 
import keyboard

def location():
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    AA1 = screen.getpixel((821,571))
    return AA1

AA1 = location()
print(AA1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define `AA1` in the `location` function, that variable cannot be used outside of the function unless you return the value of AA1, or define it as a global variable.

You would define AA1 like this

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui as pag 
import keyboard

def location(): 
    global AA1
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    AA1 = screen.getpixel((821,571))

location()
print(AA1)
```